# Need your attention with understanding of loading css background images

Tags: html, css

**I** want to know in what cases from the following the css background images will and will not load. If you can explain also the "why" in a short answer, would be very helpful.

**A**lso, if you aware of some differences between browsers in loading css background images in the following situations, please tell.

**Situation 01**

```
div { height: 300px; }
.classone {
  background-image: url("imageone.jpg");
}
.classtwo {
  background-image: url("imagetwo.jpg");
}

<div class="classone"></div>
```

**W**ould the `imagetwo.jpg` be loaded in this case?

**Situation 02**

```
div { height: 300px; }
.classone {
  background-image: url("imageone.jpg");
}
.classone {
  background-image: none;
}

<div class="classone"></div>
```

**W**ould the `imageone.jpg` be loaded in this case?

**N**ote: the `background-image: none` come after the `background-image: url("")`

Comment: While the question is pretty interesting, please explain the steps you've taken to investigate this yourself as it seems you haven't done any. Both situations can be easily checked and for more general information a simple web search yields dozens of applicable results.

Comment: @Robba ,could you please navigate me to search results you are talking about? I don't know how to check this in a "sure-way". That's why I asked it here

Comment: I simply searched for "when are css images loaded" and found some interesting results. To look and see what gets loaded, check the browser's development tools. I don't know about your platform, but for Chrome on Windows you just hit F12, then on the Network tab you can see what gets loaded. Can even filter on just images.

Comment: Thank you @Robba for helping. I found the answer for my `situation 01`(browser depended, but modern browsers won't load it), however the `situaton 02` is yet unclear to me.

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear you got your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in CSS, What comes last, takes place. So in solution 02, second definition of "classone" will replace the first one.

**Edit**

Browser downloads your entire css first, Then downloads necessary images while performing it. As your browser finds out you replaced background image, doesn't downlaod it.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mean for sure it won't pass without loading(checking) the previously set data. Or in other words - it doesn't mean the image won't be loaded. If you have any source for this, please write it

Comment: Browser downloads your entire css first, Then downloads necessary images whilte performing it. As you browser finds out you replaced background image, doesn't downlaod it.

Comment: As a proof, open up chrome inspector and go to Resouces tab. There you can actually see that your image won't be downloaded.